# How to resolve variable number of arguments problem of printf if reverse printing is not allowed

Tags: c, compiler-construction, printf, programming-languages

I am taking a course about language design and this particular question has to do with how printf in C deal with issue of variable number of arguments. In essence, I learned that printf would push arguments from the last one all the way to the format string which stores information about offsets so that the frame pointer would find the format string and then use the offset derived from the format string to find arguments' offsets.

But the question I have asks for another way to deal with this problem when reversing of arguments is not allowed. This confuses me. For now, my approach is move the frame pointer to the lowest point of the runtime stack so that it finds format string and offsets to the actuals are positive.

Please advise

Comment: The arguments are not reversed. They are pushed right-to-left onto the stack (on Intel). And it is the caller that does the pushing, not `printf`. This is the standard way on Intel of passing parameters to functions.

Comment: For `printf`, the last parameter pushed is the format string so it is the first parameter after the pushed return address and thus can easily be found by the called function. The format string gives the information of all following parameters, their type (and so their size) and so where they can be found on the stack.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Usual x86 ABI: It can be on the stack or in the registers. That depends on number of parameters passed.

Comment: @PaulOgilvie Thank you for your input. It helps me getting things clear. In this case, if format string contains information about an argument, is it the program tells the frame pointer what offset is needs to get to certain register?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you were to design a new compiler for a different calling convention, you could have the compiler push the number of actual arguments with which the call was done, or set that number in a specific register such as RAX/EAX, which will be overridden anyway.

Another option would be to redefine the `printf()` API to have the format string as the last parameter. In this way you will have all you need to access the stack looking for your parameters.

Comment: Thank you Costantino for your input!It's interesting to fix this issue in these ways. I will have to make sure if the question requires any convention to prevent such solutions.

Comment: Were it not for a desire to support non-prototyped functions, the sensible way to handle variadic arguments would have been to have variadic functions behave as though passed a va_list, with a special syntax to indicate that a va_list argument should be passed to the called function rather than wrapped as a single argument in another va_list.

Answer (score 2):

1. Format string does not store information about offsets only contains the information on what and how to print.
2. How parameters are passed to the function is defined by the ABI. Every hardware architecture and implementation may use different ABI - thus pass the parameters in a different way. Usually some number parameters a passed in the registers, other on the stack.
3. If you want to define your own ABI I advice to read how it was done before: https://wiki.osdev.org/Calling_Conventions

The first parameter on x86-64 from the left will be saved in the EDI register.

Comment: Thank you for your input! A few questions here: first, how does the frame pointer in this case of printf knows the needed offset to get to each register? Second, could you remind me what an ABI is?

Comment: https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Application_binary_interface